# Search bar width doesn't adapt to window size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a search bar that adapts to my window size, I've tried to flex-grow but it doesn't change anything my bar is still the same width.

Also, I have a second question since I'm quite new to web development. I come across a website like Frontend Mentor that gives you nice projects to work with but I have issues with the stylesheet. For example, they ask for the font size to be 15px but when I make it  15px on my stylesheet it's way too big and doesn't look like what it is supposed to look like.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
  flex-grow: 1;
  left: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 9px;
  border: 0.5px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 0.5px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 0.5px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 7px;
}

.box:focus {
  border-color: blue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0.5px 0 0 rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com/search" class="container">
  <input class="box" type="text" name="as_q">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`flex-grow` works on a flex item. "container" is not a flex item, so `flex-grow` will not have effect on it. You have to set

```
.container{
    display:flex
}
```

Now the childrens of "container" will be "flex" items. You apply the "flex-grow" to the children.

```
.box{
  flex-grow:1
}
```

"flex-grow" value is the rate of growth. Since you have only one child, it will take up the rest of the available space. If you had 2 children, first has "flex-grow:1", second has "flex-grow:2", second child will take up double  size of the first one.

For your second question, please create another question and explain it with detail, include all the code. Each question should be focused on only one question.